# geoserver load image mosaics tiff files

Tags: raster, geoserver, image-mosaic

I have a massive amount of tiff files (+prj. all together 100k). For test purpose I have loaded a small bit of these into geoserver and worked fine. But when I try to add to the store the data folder what contains all of the images, it is just loading nothing else happening. Is there any way to load these amount of rasters into geoserver?

Comment: "It is just loading and nothing else happens". For what amount of time? I'd suppose that to open and scan 100k files in order to produce a index, a significant amount of time would be needed. Assuming just 20ms per file (which is just a guess, could be worse, especially if the files are on a network drive) one would have to wait 0.02 * 100000 = 2000 seconds, that is, more than half an hour...

Comment: It has finished with timeout, however the store is saved, and I could check the index shape file. But still I cannot see the rasters, not in the openlayer preview... Should I have to increase the performance of the geoserver somehow? I have 16GB of RAM.

Comment: You cannot hope to actually see 100k rasters in a single shot, it will take too much time to load and render them. Setup scale dependencies in your layer so that the layer shows only when very zoomed in, when the display contains only a few files (e.g., < 50) and then zoom in enough in the layer preview.

Comment: Thanks for your help, as I see after a couple of hours of googleing I have to build image pyramid and publish that one.